# LXDe in Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, lxd

Translation by Google:

I would like to know in Lubuntu 18.04 the LXDe shell will be installed by default or will it have to be installed before? And tell me how to install it should be installed in addition?

Original:

Я бы хотел узнать в lubuntu 18.04 оболочка lxqt будет установлено по умолчанию или её надо будет до устанавливать? И подскажите как её установить есть надо устанавливать дополнительно?

Comment: "Lubuntu is a faster, more lightweight and energy saving, official flavour of Ubuntu **using LXDE**, the Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment. " (from https://lubuntu.me/about/ ). So it is preinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

LXDE is the default desktop for Lubuntu 18.04. The project plans to switch to Lxqt but this has not yet happened.